# What does "weak continuity of the norm" means?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, weak-convergence, weak-topology

I am trying to read an article about $C^*$-algebras but I am stuck in one passage in wich the autor is estimating the value of sequences of linear functionals $\omega_{1,n}$ and $\omega_{2,n}^A$ that converge weakly to $\omega_{1}$ and $\omega_{2}^A$ respectively, being that

$$\omega_{1,n}(b) = \langle \psi_{1,n}\,\, ,\pi_n(b)\psi_{1,n}\rangle$$

$$\omega_{2,n}^A(b) = \langle \psi_{2,n}\,\, ,\frac{\pi(A^*bA)}{\omega_{2,n}(A^*A)}\psi_{2,n}\rangle$$

$$\omega_{2,n}(b)= \langle \psi_{2,n}\,\, ,\pi_n(b)\psi_{2,n}\rangle$$

so that

$$\omega_{2,n}(A^*A) = \langle \psi_{2,n}\,\, ,\pi_n(A^*A)\psi_{2,n}\rangle=\langle \pi_n(A)\psi_{2,n}\,\, ,\pi_n(A)\psi_{2,n}\rangle$$

and knowing that $||\omega_{1} - \omega_{2}^A|| = 2$

he says that "by the weak continuity of the norm":

$$||\omega_{1,n} - \omega_{2,n}^A||^2\leq 4 - 4\frac{|\langle\psi_{1,n}\,\,,\pi_n(A)\psi_{2,n}\rangle|^2}{||\pi_n(A)\psi_{2,n}||^2}$$

I imagine that $||\pi_n(A)\psi_{2,n}||^2= \left(\sqrt{\omega_{2,n}(A^*A)}\right)^2 = \langle \pi_n(A)\psi_{2,n}\,\, ,\pi_n(A)\psi_{2,n}\rangle$

But how can I get the cross-term ?

I have tried to do this in the following way:

$$||\omega_{1,n} - \omega_{2,n}^A||^2 \leq |\omega_{1,n}(b)-\omega_{2,n}^A(b) |^2 = \Bigg\vert\langle \psi_{1,n}\,\, , \pi_n(b)\psi_{1,n}\rangle - \frac{\langle\psi_{2,n}, \pi_n(A^*bA)\psi_{2,n} \rangle}{\langle\psi_{2,n}, \pi_n(A^*A)\psi_{2,n} \rangle}\Bigg\vert^2$$

I then thoght of using something like an polarization identity like $||u-v||^2 = ||u||^2 + ||v||^2 - 2\langle u,v\rangle$ and ignoring one of the squared norms in the right hand side to get an inequality, but I don't think that is the way.

Does the term "weak continuity of the norm" mean anything? I googled it and didn't find anything except the very article I am reading.

(FYI the article is "Quantum theory of measurement and
macroscopic observables" by Klaus Hepp)

Comment: My first guess would be that this means that the norm is continuous with respect to the [weak topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology).  I am not going to read the paper in detail, but the phrase you cite occurs in the proof of Lemma 3, which has to do with the convergence of certain sequences in the weak topology so this isn't an entirely unreasonable guess, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When he says "weak continuity of the norm", it looks like he doesn't refer to the inequality, but rather to the other side,
$$
\|\omega_{1,n}-\omega_{2,n}^A\|\to2. 
$$
Still, the terminology is at least unusual.

It's a bit annoying to write all the details. But basically what happens is that because $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are disjoint, there "almost" exists a projection $p$ with $\omega_1(p)=1$, $\omega_2(1-p)=1$. Properly, this projection is guaranteed to exist if $\mathcal A$ is a von Neumann algebra; but in general it exists in $\mathcal A''$ and one can work with approximations in $\mathcal A$. Then
\begin{align}
\|\omega_{1,n}-\omega_{2,n}\|&\geq|\omega_{1,n}(2p-1)-\omega_{2,n}(2p-1)|\to|\omega_1(2p-1)-\omega_2(2p-1)|\\[0.3cm]&=|\omega_1(p)+\omega_2(1-p)|=2. 
\end{align}

The inequality, on the other hand, is standard but not trivial. Basically, what happens is that if $\alpha(X)=\langle \psi, X\psi\rangle$, $\beta(X)=\langle \phi, X\phi\rangle$ are states (that is, $\|\psi\|=\|\phi\|=1$), then
$$
\|\alpha-\beta\|=2\sqrt{1-|\langle \psi,\phi\rangle|^2}.
$$

**Edit:** I have included a proof of the norm equality [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4151108/22857).